# Number of decimals in prestashop 1.7 not working

Tags: prestashop, decimalformat, prestashop-1.7

I fixed the `Number of decimals` in the prestashop 1.7 backoffice to "3". But prices are always displayed with 2 decimals after point. It's a bug in prestashop 1.7, but nothing found in prestashop forums.

Answer (score 0):

To set the amount of decimal digits to 3 in Prestashop, open:

`root/translations/cldr/main--xx-XX--numbers`

then change

```
"standard":"#,##0.00\u00a0\u00a4"
```

to

```
"standard":"#,##0.000\u00a0\u00a4"
```

Where xx-XX is language you're using. For example: `en-US`.

Comment: I don't know why the one can want 3 decimal numbers, but seems they fixed that already. Check the latest version (1.7.1.2).

Comment: same problem with PS 1.7.1.2

Comment: Yeah, I know. The solution above is still working though.

Comment: @Goujon because some currencies use 3 digits perhaps?!